Calculate a measure difference between two rows in Power BI



Fisc
20-21
21-22
22-23
23-24
24-25




A
10
15
30
25
5


B
100
85
35
15
30



this is the initial table imported from Excel in Power Bi :
Table name : prog
I want to create a measure to calculate the difference between rows to display a table like the Following:




20-21
21-22
22-23
23-24
24-25




Diff B-A
90
60
5
-10
25



this is what i used but doesn't work :
_DiffB-A = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('prog'[B]) - SUM('prog'[A]),
    ALL('prog'[Fisc])
)

I tried to use the index but all solution are adding a new column and not a row.
Thanks.

Wouldn't that measure return an error? Since A and B aren't column names, so you can't do 'prog'[A]

you can try this

In power query, select the first column and unpivot other columns



then create a measure
Measure = CALCULATE(sum(prog[Value]),prog[Fisc]="B")- CALCULATE(sum(prog[Value]),prog[Fisc]="A")


